# Calculate average of time with fraction of seconds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have 3 different columns of timestamps in a pandas dataframe, two of which have fraction of seconds recorded while the third does not have fraction of seconds. I would like to calculate an average of these 3 columns.

I have already tried to compute the average using the mean function on the columns and consistently received nan as the result

```py
import pandas as pd 
data = [{'time1': '2018-07-22 04:34:10.8966', 'time2': '2017-07-22 04:34:10.8966', 'time3': '2018-07-27 00:10:04'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['estimate'] = df[['time1', 'time2', 'time3']].mean(axis=1)
df
```

Expected : An average of the 3 timestamps 
Actual : While there is no error, it also always evaluates to nan which is not what is desired.

Comment: Check your dtypes. I bet those datetimes are actually strings. Use [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) to make them actual datetime objects.

Comment: @Noleli although the columns in the example above are strings, converting them with `to_datetime()` to `datetime64[ns]` and then calling `mean()` on these columns will still result in `NaN`, as stated by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't to it directly on datetime values, you need to convert them, average, and then convert back:

```
data = [{'time1': '2018-07-22 04:34:10.8966', 'time2': '2017-07-22 04:34:10.8966', 'time3': '2018-07-27 00:10:04'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['estimate'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['time1', 'time2', 'time3']].values.astype(pd.np.int64).mean(axis=1))
```

Result:

```
                       time1                      time2               time3                      estimate
0 2018-07-22 04:34:10.896600 2017-07-22 04:34:10.896600 2018-07-27 00:10:04 2018-03-24 03:06:08.597733376
```